# Is it possible to restore backup from Solr 6.0 to Solr 6.1?

Tags: solr, backup, database-backups

I am trying to restore backup (migrate) index from Solr 6.0 to Solr 6.1. However, when I follow the steps on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups , I get an Exception Error saying it failed when I use

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/replication?command=restorestatus
```

command to check the status.

The actual response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="restorestatus"><str name="snapshotName">snapshot.20160802100744911</str><str name="status">failed</str><str name="exception">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while restoring the backup index</str></lst>
</response>
```

I was thinking it is possible to restore backup made from a previous version of Solr to a newer one, but am I wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an application to do this, it is available on github:

https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json

The idea behind the code is simple, when you query a collection using the Solrj, even an entire collection, it returns a stream documents (i.e. `SolrDocument`).
And `SolrDocument` implements both `Map<String,Object>`, `Serializable`.

So I thought I could serialise the documents in json. Well, take a look at the repo, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

So, after several hours of trying hard, I've figured out the solution.

First, a response from the Solr saying OK like below does not mean it's done... (That was my first mistake) The restoration file I was using was corrupt (partially made).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">8</int></lst><str name="status">OK</str>
</response>
```

Next, I was looking at the logs, and it said that it was out of memory, and kept dying because the restore file was 13GB big and certainly wasn't enough with the default Solr configuration.

I restarted Solr with

```
./solr restart -m 16g
```

And it was successfully imported.

Lesson learned: be patient, and think about memory size.